# Using click.command to make a function as a command

Tags: python, command, python-click

I am trying to make the function `log` into a command using the following code inside `simple.py`:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', count=True)
def log(verbose):
    click.echo(f"Verbosity: {verbose}")
```

When I type the following on the command terminal:`log -vvv` , I get an error as : `Command 'log' not found, but there are 16 similar ones.`

`@click.command` should have converted the function `log` into a command? But, it doesn't work here. Could someone explain,please? Thanks!

I have tried the following commands:

```
log -vvv
Command 'log' not found, but there are 16 similar ones.
```

```
python3 simple.py log
Usage: simple.py [OPTIONS]
Try 'simple.py --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (log)
```

Could someone please explain what does `@click.command()` actually do and how's it different from running simple.py. The documentation does not make it very clear to me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', count=True)
def log(verbose):
    click.echo(f"Verbosity: {verbose}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log()
```

Then calling it like

```
$ python simple.py    
Verbosity: 0

$ python simple.py -v
Verbosity: 1
```

The way you try to run it, suggest you think about command group, i.e. [nesting commands](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/quickstart/#nesting-commands)

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command('log')
@click.option('-v', '--verbose', count=True)
def log(verbose):
    click.echo(f"Verbosity: {verbose}")

@cli.command('greet')
def greet():
    click.echo("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Then

```
$ python simple.py greet
Hello

$ python simple.py log -v -v # or just -vv
Verbosity: 2
```

Next step would be [setuptools integration](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/setuptools/?highlight=setuptools), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the first method: `python simple.py`  would do the same thing when `simple.py` had no click decorators. What difference has importing click made then?

Comment: The difference is the option. The alternative would be to use e.g. `argparse` to achieve the same and it will not be 1 line